# Generate JWT token in Django view on form submit without DRF

Tags: python, django, jwt

I would like to know how can I generate a JWT token in django based on some fields which I get from a form submit in the view. This toke is not used authentication in django but I need to pass this token back in response which will then be sent to another service using JavaScript.

I am not using DRF currently.

The flow will be something like

`FrontEnd -> Form submit -> Django Backend generate JWT -> Send back to FrontEnd in response`

Again this is not for authentication on django.

If someone can point me to a working example that will definitely help me out.

Regards,
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.

Use the python library called `pyjwt`

code example (JWTvalid for 1 hour)

```
import jwt
import datetime
exp_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
JWT_PAYLOAD = {
        "context": {
            "user": {
                "name": "My Name",
                "email": "My Email",
            },
            "iss": "My ISS",
            "exp": int(exp_time.timestamp()),
            "iat": int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()),
        }
    }
jwt_token = jwt.encode(JWT_PAYLOAD, settings.JWT_SECRET, algorithm='HS256')
```